# How can I load only relevant scripts in my scripts section in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a home page and a login, behind the login will be at least 1 system that the home page scripts section doesn't need to know about.  It's going to be secured, but I don't want to load the system's controllers on my home page, what is the best practice for having a set of scripts load on the home page and another set of scripts load when I hit my logged in system?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=angularjs+lazy+load+modules.  There are 100 results there, depending on which script loader you want to use.  (do you want to use requirejs, webpack, systemjs, or something else?)

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I wasn't sure where to even begin my search, that link has plenty.  I'll give one of those a shot.